# how to model my game project in functional programming concept with OCAML?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm currently in a project of making a video game, to be specific, a turn-based strategy in OCAML. It's a coursework about functional programming, so the more functional programming the better, but if I can't do it with functional programming, I can use OOP if REALLY needed.

Here's the model of my game at the basic level :

In the following, when I say `type`, I actually mean `instance/type/module`, i.e. I don't know how I should implement it, but I know that they should be at least packaged into different sections.

There will be a `Main` type. It's role is to switch between menus, settings, and the actual game.

The `Game` type will run the game. In context, it will iterate over each `Faction` of the game, and iterate, within the `Faction`, each `Unit` that the faction has. Each `Unit` will have a specific behaviour attached to it.

Every game object ( that can be rendered in a 2D screen ) will have the `GameObject` type. Ideally, I can attach a bunch of video/audio/etc. renderer and I will be able to know their position on the map.

`Grid` will be an array of array composed of `Tile`. `Grid` has a global view over the game, from `Grid`, I can, for example, know the location of every `GameObject` in the `Game`

`Tile` is a tile on the grid. Eventually, I would like them to have special features, for example, a terrain type.

`Unit` ( not to be confused with `unit` type from OCAML ) is an entity controlled by a `Faction`. It has many attributes, such as health, mana, strength etc...  and can do certain actions depending on who they are.

`Faction` represents either the player or one of the opponents. Some bonus apply depending on the faction. e.g. a faction could have greater health, but lower strength and vice-versa.

`Action` is a type that represents an action. It has a source and a destination attributes. It can represent, any type of action, from self healing to an AOE spell. It has access to `Game` so that it can be free to do whatever it pleases within the `Game`.

My goal is to make a game model that I can improve on progressively. For instance, I would like to make subclasses of unit, those who can attack from afar, and those who can only attack in melee etc.

If this was a OOP project, it would be pretty straightforward, albeit inefficient if I understood the previous comments. As you can see, my way of thinking is biased towards OOP because I haven't done any project of this scale without OOP. My goal here is to make it in Functional Programming.

I require your advice on how to implement what I described, or part of it so I can figure out the rest on my own.

Thank you.

EDIT: Edited the whole question
EDIT2: Some spelling and backticks

Comment: https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/entities-components-and-systems-89c31464240d

Comment: Your question seems to be phrased as asking how to do implementation inheritance in functional programming, which you can't because it's fundamentally an OO concept (although implementation inheritance is discouraged even in the OO-world where you should favour composition).  It would be better to reformulate your question in terms of how you model your game using FP concepts.

Comment: understood, should i modify my question in place or make a new one?

Comment: I would probably suggest editing

Comment: You're still assuming OOP idioms. I think it would be better to ask this kind of question in a more conversational forum, like [discuss.ocaml.org](https://discuss.ocaml.org/), since that lends itself better to clarifications and exploration. SO is best suited for specific, well-defined programming problems.

Comment: See also: http://cranialburnout.blogspot.com/

Comment: The fact that you're planning a turn based game is quite helpful from a functional perspective.  You could capture the state of the game in some kind of `GameState` type, capture the instructions given in a turn in something like an `Instructions` type and have a function that generates a new `GameState` from the old `GameState` and some `Instructions`.

Comment: @TheInnerLight i have thought about that, that's exactly what i'm going to do. the game state will be a variant type, which either is the game state itself, or a tuple of the previous gamestate and the modification on said game state

Answer (score 0):

Your question is filled with imperative and OOP idioms: iterate, array, object, subclasses, ... So your mind set seems to be already made up.

Not surprising as GUIs and games are the most obvious examples for OOP. They have state and mutate over time and thrive on inheritance. And while you can do all those things functionally, with functors or with with first class modules I don't think it is worth it.

Luckily ocaml lends itself well to this. Records and classes can have mutable fields and ocamls classes can model your objects and inheritance nicely. And you still can use all the functional concepts of ocaml alongside the classes. It mixes well.

Comment: my mindset is already set up but i need to change it as i need to avoid using OOP and imperative concepts as much as possible!

Comment: It's always possible. What I'm saying is that it isn't convenient. If you want your game source to be readable, easy to understand and maintain then you have to make a compromise. Use OOP and imperative feature where they make more sense. Which basically means your units, buildings and map tiles should be mutable records or objects.

Comment: I think I agree. I'll use classes to represent the game. The rest can be done functionally right? Like advancing through the game, managing the video/audio for each entity etc